# Issue appending ndarray's with different shapes

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy `ndarray` with shape (25,2) and I am trying to append one more value that has shape (2,).

I have tried using the `append` method, but so far no luck.

Any thoughts? 
Thanks!

Comment: You can use `np.vstack`. It doesn't work in-place, so you have to assign back: `a = np.vstack([a, b])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of errors did you get with the `append method`?  'no luck' is as bad a descriptor as 'didnt work'.  In a proper question you should show the expected value along with errors.  However this topic comes up often enough that we can make good guesses.

```
In [336]: a = np.ones((3,2),int)
In [337]: b = np.zeros((2,),int)
```

But first I'll be pedantic and try an `append method`:

```
In [338]: a.append(b)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-338-d6231792f85d> in <module>()
----> 1 a.append(b)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

`lists` have an append method; numpy arrays do not.

There is a poorly named `append` function:

```
In [339]: np.append(a,b)
Out[339]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
In [340]: _.reshape(-1,2)
Out[340]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 0]])
```

That works - in a way.  But if I read the docs, and provide an axis parameter:

```
In [341]: np.append(a,b, axis=0)
...
-> 5166     return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Now it is just calling `np.concatenate`, turning the 2 arguments into a list.

If this is the error you got, and didn't understand it, you may need to review basic numpy docs about dimensions and shapes.

`a` is 2d, `b` is 1d.  To concatenate, we need to reshape `b` so it is `(1,2)`, a shape that is compatible with the (3,2) of `a`.  There are several ways of doing that:

```
In [342]: np.concatenate((a, b.reshape(1,2)), axis=0)
Out[342]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 0]])
```

Stay away from the `np.append`; it's too confusing for many beginners, and   doesn't add anything significant to the base `concatenate`.

Comment: Thank you!!! The 'np.concatenate((a, b.reshape(1,2)), axis=0)' was perfect!

Answer (score 1):

For append to work in this way you'll need to satisfy two conditions specified in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html).

1. The appended object must have the same dimensions. It should be of shape `(1, 2)`.
2. You must specify an axis to concatenate, otherwise numpy will flatten the arrays.

For example:

```
import numpy
x = numpy.ones((3, 2))
y = [[1, 2]]
numpy.append(x, y, axis=0)
```

Results in:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.]])
```